# Google Map doesn't work on release version with proguard

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I was testing my application in debug mode and everything was fine but when I built it the signed apk google maps stopped working.

Current code:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

What is my problem here?

Comment: Did you add your release key to your google api console project?

Comment: no how to do that and where should i add? and where is the release key? @DavidMedenjak

Comment: You must have done the same steps already for your debug key. And the release key is the one you sign your release build with. The official guidelines:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#release-cert

Comment: i get the sha key from keytool and add it in google api and get the key but it doesn't work again @DavidMedenjak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Android key from the google console https://console.developers.google.com/
using a release certificate (not a debug certificate), and this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup will help you to find the difference between them,

But note, you should uninstall the app (that use the key in the debug certificate) from your phone, then install again the app (that use the key in the release certificate).

Comment: Do you see the Logcat messages ? it may be help us to find the problem.